# Цельные и свободные словосочетания

Tags: синтаксис

Октябрьская революция, Французская революция, Буржуазно-демократическая революция - цельные словосочетания?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Октябрьская революция, Французская революция** - имена собственные, составные наименования. Их следует  отнести к **нечленимым сочетаниям** по следующим признакам:основную информационную нагрузку несет грамматически зависимое слово (в данном случае прилагательное).

**Буржуазно-демократическая революция** - сочетание не является именем собственным (пишется со строчной буквы), обозначает конкретный вид революции. Это  свободное словосочетание,  в таких сочетаниях семантически главное слово "революция" является и грамматически главным.